# Gigabig USB Ethernet adapter at 100 Mbos

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ethernet

I have a USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter (Sitecom LN-032) plugged to a USB 3.0 port.

However, it's still set up as a 100Mbps:
[image]

I suspect that some driver needs to be installed. However, the manufacturer doesn't supply any for Linux.

Any other idea? Is there a generic driver that I could use?

**ADDED INFORMATION:**

```
$ ethtool enx64d1a34f6bb4
Settings for enx64d1a34f6bb4:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 32
    Transceiver: internal
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Please run `ip a` to find out ethernet adapter's name and then `ethtool adapter_name` and paste the last output to your original question.

Comment: You probably have a cable problem, or you're plugging into a 100Mb port on your switch or router. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables?

Comment: Any hint as to how I can identify the adapter from the list returned by `ip a`?

Comment: Type `ip a  | grep -B1 ether`. On the output note the name after the number and `:`. For example, it may be something like `enp3s0f1`, `enp0s3`, `eth0` etc. As another alternative method, you can note the first word of the `nmcli device status | grep ethernet` command's output.

Answer (score 1):

My (silly) mistake: I took the wrong cat 5 cable! I would have never thought that the OS would detect it, though!